# Why are my CLOB values returning null for this view?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query, based on another, key query, The key query gets the data for us, and then automatic view processing code does various manipulations to formulate a query it can execute. This is so that all views are processed in the same way. IOW, this first excerpt is what is sent to the server when I tell it to execute the real query, which is too large for here and runs perfectly anyway.

```
WITH
  data AS (
    SELECT
      list_attributeSheets.name,
      list_attributeSheets.attributeValue,
      list_attributeSheets.ciid,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY list_attributeSheets.name ASC) AS rowNumber,
      5 AS queryUserId
    FROM
      list_attributeSheets
    WHERE
      list_attributeSheets.ciid = 14
  )
SELECT
  data.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data) AS totalRowCount
FROM
  data
WHERE
  data.rowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 25
ORDER BY
  data.name ASC
```

The problem is all values for `list_attributeSheets.attributeValue` return as `null`. If I run a direct query, like `select attributeValue from list_attributeSheets` then all the numeric values come back properly.

I say numeric, but the columns are actually first all cast to `CLOB`, for the numerics to match `CIAttributeValue.textValue`. There are four exclusive value columns, and I coalesce them into whichever one is not null. I couldn't get Oracles's `coalesce` to co-operate so I just went with a good old `CASE`:

```
CASE
    WHEN (CIAttributeValue.textValue IS NOT NULL AND DBMS_LOB.getlength(CIAttributeValue.textValue)>0) THEN TO_CLOB(CIAttributeValue.textValue)
    WHEN (CIAttributeValue.booleanValue IS NOT NULL) THEN TO_CLOB(CIAttributeValue.booleanValue)
    WHEN (CIAttributeValue.numberValue IS NOT NULL) THEN TO_CLOB(CIAttributeValue.numberValue)
    WHEN (CIAttributeValue.dateValue IS NOT NULL) THEN TO_CLOB(CIAttributeValue.dateValue)
END AS AttributeValue
```

Oracle generates such reems of DDL for a table, I have extracted the essential bits:

```
CREATE TABLE CIATTRIBUTEVALUE 
(
  CIATTRVALUEID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, CIID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, CIATTRTYPEID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, TEXTVALUE NCLOB 
, BOOLEANVALUE NUMBER(3, 0) 
, NUMBERVALUE NUMBER 
, DATEVALUE DATE 
, ISLOGICALLYDELETED NUMBER(3, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL 
, ISRECYCLED NUMBER(3, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT PK_CIATTRIBUTEVALUE PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    CIATTRVALUEID 
  )
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE CIATTRIBUTETYPE 
(
  CIATTRTYPEID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, CITYPEID NUMBER(10, 0) 
, SUBTYPEID NUMBER(10, 0) 
, NAME NVARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL 
, DATAENTRYTYPE NUMBER(3, 0) NOT NULL 
, GROUPNAME NVARCHAR2(100) 
, ISLOGICALLYDELETED NUMBER(3, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL 
, ISRECYCLED NUMBER(3, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL 
, DATATYPE NUMBER(3, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL 
, ACCESSLEVELID NUMBER(10, 0) 
, ISREQUIRED NUMBER(3, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL 
, DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR2(150) 
, CONSTRAINT PK_CIATTRIBUTETYPE PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    CIATTRTYPEID 
  )
```

Comment: Seems to work OK for me in 11.2.0.3 and 10.2.0.5, if I've understood your set-up (with `textValue` as CLOB, `list_attributeSheets` as a view with your case plus other columns from `CIAttributeValue`). [Or in 11.2.0.2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf197/1). Which version are you using, and/or what am I doing differently? Can you add the DDL for the table and view to the question?